# Change Django Celery beat interval

Tags: django, redis, celery

I'm newbie with Django Celery, I ran this command:

```
celery -A projectname beat -l info
```

It print that `maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)`

I want to extend it to 10 minutes, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Param --max_interval

```
celery -A projectname beat --max-interval 600
```